# Making localhost slower

Tags: performance, localhost

I'm working on a project and I would like to test it on slow connections too, is there any tool you would suggest for doing this?

Comment: There is no source code, no programming language spec, so this is either not a SO question (and should be migrated to SU, or SF), or you should add how you connect and communicate in detail by posting some source code.

Comment: You can use plugins for Firefox like Firefox Throttle to cap the up- and download rates.

Comment: Search around for load testing tools.  That, or start encoding a dozen or so videos in the background while you accept HTTP requests.

Comment: There are a lot of [similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=simulate+slow+connection+localhost) - which solutions have you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are under GNU/Linux, take a look at this: [How to simulate a slow network with 'wanem'](http://blogs.kde.org/node/3031)

And yes, this post probably belongs to Server fault.

Answer (score -1):

**STEP 1:**

Download/install a freeware proxy server that has bandwidth throttling. 
If your testing is for HTTP specifically you only need an HTTP proxy server, else you need a SOCKS proxy server.

**STEP 2**

Setup the proxy to throttle your connection to 56k/dial-up speeds.

**STEP 3**

If your testing is HTTP specific just set your browser(s) to use the proxy, else you'll have to configure your application to use the SOCKS proxy when making connections.

If the OP defines what programming language and operating system is used, then STEPS 1 and 3 can be elaborated on further.

Comment: How is that making localhost slower?  The OP didn't even say they want to do tests in the browser. ... -1

Comment: @hroptatyr - From the question, "I want to test it on slow connections too". I'd say throttling the "connection" with a proxy server achieves this end. But your semantic argument aside, do you have a useful suggestion?

Comment: why are slow connections == http over tcp/ip?  And yes, depending on the OS traffic shaping, for instance Linux' `tc` tool or BSD's `ipfw`

Comment: Your suggestion is a commercial Windows only solution.

Comment: @hroptatyr - Using a SOCKS proxy with bandwidth throttling would work too. Should I list all of the free proxy servers I can find on Google or leave that up to the reader? I'll update my answer to be a bit broader. Perhaps you could offer a solution yourself.

Comment: you can do that, I think the question is too broad and I voted to close it, also AD7six's search for similar questions covers it all in my eyes